# Getting a null exception after selecting value from drop down list, value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added more fields to my registerViewModel class of which one of the is the collection of Membershiptypes through migration then I have also modified my Accountcontroller and my `register.cshtml` so that I can have a drop down list. So when I try to select the items in the dropdown list I'm receiving a `null exception` and the application breaks, it doesn't create the user anymore.

This is my RegisterViewmodel.

```
public class RegisterViewModel{      

   public ICollection<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

this is my get method.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    using (var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
    {
        RegisterViewModel newUser = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            MembershipTypes = db.MembershipTypes.ToList(),
            BirthDate = DateTime.Now
        };
            return View(newUser);
    }
}
```

This is my post method.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            BirthDate = model.BirthDate,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Phone = model.Phone,
            MembershipTypeId = model.MembershipTypeId,
            Disable = false
        };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
}
```

And my RegisterView is like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MembershipTypeId, "MembershipTypeId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"),"Select List", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When I register the user it should go to the database but it doesn't initialize the membershipTypes in the result variable hence it throws an exception that value cannot be null.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the exception? It should tell you where the exception happens which will help you identify why.

Comment: Do you have data in the membershipType table?

Comment: Try building your `SelectList` in your controller then pass it to your view. In your controller you would have `List<SelectListItem> MembershipTypesDropDown = new List<SelectListItem>();` then after your `db` grab of `MembershipTypes` populate your list. It would look something like `MembershipTypes.ForEach(n => MembershipTypesDropDown.Add(new SelectListItem()
{
 Text = n.ID.Tostring(),
 Value = n.Name
}
));` then your view would be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MembershipTypeId, Model.MembershipTypesDropDown, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Yes I do have data in my membershipType table,Alright thanks let me try that.